# What tense is this: "Why'd you make him live all those years alone?"

Tags: american-english, past-simple, writing, informal-language, contractions

In the movie "Something big" with Dean Martin, Mr. Baker asks colonel's wife:
"Why'd you make him live all those years alone?"
What tense is that? Grammary suggest me:
Why'd you made him live all those years alone?
But I hear "make" as it writes in the subtitle.
Does it some with "should", as:
Why should you make him live all those years alone?
If I'm writing:
Why did you make him live all those years alone?
Grammarly there was no suggestion. But, if I'm writing:
Why'd you make him live all those years alone?
Grammarly corects to:
Why'd you made him live all those years alone?
If it is not "did", it can be only some modal, and I think it is "should" but I'm not sure and because I have just created this question.

Comment: *Why'd you **made** him live all those years alone* is ungrammatical. Was that a typo or actually what Grammarly (not "Grammary") suggested? If it was the *actual* suggestion, then it's an error. (But if it's just a typo, I don't see any difference at all between the original sentence and the suggested sentence.)

Comment: Sorry I do not understand "I don't see any difference at all between the original sentence and the suggested sentence"

Comment: Does it mean: Why'd you make him live all those years alone? = Why did you make him live all those years alone?

Comment: Why should you make him live all those years alone? = Grammarly there is no red line.

Comment: Look at your second sentence and your fourth sentence. The *only* difference between them is that the second sentence uses **make** but the fourth sentence uses **made**. Are you saying that Grammarly suggests you use an ungrammatical sentence?

Comment: Do you think "Why'd you make..." means "Why did you make ..."?

Comment: @JasonBassford *Why'd you made him live all those years alone* is very much grammatical in Standard English assuming a correct interpretation of *'d*.

Comment: @userr2684291  what do you see as the " correct interpretation of 'd"? I don't see any plausible meaning for "why'd" other than "why did" in this context.

Comment: @DavidSiegel There is no context, so it can be either *did* or *had*. (The correct interpretation of *'d* is *had* provided the sentence is indeed *Why'd you made him...*)

Comment: @userr2684291 The context is the quoted line "Why'd you make him live all those years alone?" nor do i think "why had you made him..." good grammar, although it is not absolutely wrong, in my view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is shortened from:

> Why did you make him live all those years alone?

The verb is make. The action of "making him live alone" occurred in the past, and is complete, as I understand this.

> Why did you go to Florida last week?

is the same grammatical structure.

Comment: It is ok if it writes like that, Why did... . But Why'd you make him live all those years alone? Grammarly correct to Why'd you made him live all those years alone?

Comment: Grammarly is wrong. It is presumably failing to recognise "Why'd" as a rapid form of "Why did". Note that "Why'd" is not a conventional form like "I'm" or "he'd": _'d_ is a customary contraction of "had" or "would", but not of "did".

Comment: This just shows that automated tools such as Grammerly still have limits. Here is has "corrected" an unusual but valid form to one that is flatly wrong.